# Batch rename folders to files

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, rename, dos

I have a parent folder with lots of folders (movies) underneath. Each folder has 1 file (the actual movie).

I would like some advice on a batch script that I can run to rename the folders to the file (movie) within excluding the extension (.avi)

e.g.

BEFORE

```
Parent (folder)
  Folder 1
    Movie 1.avi

  Folder 2
    Movie 2.avi
```

AFTER

```
Parent (folder)
  Movie 1
    Movie 1.avi

  Movie 2
    Movie 2.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
  FOR %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a\*") DO IF /i "%%~na" NEQ "%%~nb" ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%~nb"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

You would need to set your directory as `sourcedir`. I set my testing directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file does the job:

```
@echo off
if exist "%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat" del "%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat" >nul
cd /D "Complete\path\to\parent\folder"
for /R "Complete\path\to\parent\folder" %%I in (*.avi) do echo ren "%%~dpI" "%%~nI">>"%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat"
if exist "%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat" (
   call "%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat"
   del "%TEMP%\RenameFolders.bat" >nul
)
```

**"Complete\path\to\parent\folder"** must be modified twice in the batch file by real parent folder path.

The main job is done by command `FOR`. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` to get information about option

- `/R` ... recursive folder/file scan, and
- `%%~dpI` ... drive and path of file, and
- `%%~nI` ... name of file without path and file extension.

For each *.avi file the command `echo` is executed to create the rename command used later to rename the folder containing the *.avi file to the name of the *.avi file.

It is not possible to do the folder rename directly within the `FOR` loop as it is not possible to rename a folder while it is the current working directory for a running process. Each folder is the current working directory for the batch process while `FOR` is running.

The command `CD` in third line just makes sure that the working directory is set to parent folder of all the subfolders to rename to avoid that renaming a folder fails because the batch file is started from one of the subfolders.

The second line just makes sure there is no file `RenameFolders.bat` in the folder for termporary files for example when terminating this batch file once by click on button **X** while command `FOR` is currently running.

After command `FOR` processed recursively all *.avi files and a line with command `ren` was appended to file `RenameFolders.bat` for each file, this created batch file is called which renames now the folders.

Last the batch file temporarily created is deleted as not needed anymore.